# Fastest way to search through files

Tags: windows, search, windows-search, file-search, search-folder

I'm making a software that would count the amount of files stored in the hard drive(s) ordered by extension. The software collects such data as: file name, extension, file size, file create date, file modify date and location.

However searching throughout the entire computer takes up a lot of time.

I'm asking to know what is the fastest way to search through files?

What possible ways are there to maximize search speed?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably already using the functions [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) and [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx) ([MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(VS.85).aspx)).

The only way to further speed-up the program is to make it multi-thread and
divide the work among the threads in an intelligent manner.

Comment: I'm searching using Delphi XE IOUtils among all files on system until there are no more files to find. I sort of firstly build a tree view of all folders and files on the system and then create grouped lists with information. I'm already using multi-theading by dividing the amount of search files to 100 per thread (4 threads top).

Comment: I don't know this product. I just hope that you're using directory-traversal functions rather than file-attribute ones. You shouldn't be dividing files among threads but rather directories. For full control, using Windows API through C/C++ is the best way of knowing that it does what is expected and nothing else.